# Счётчик символов в каждом предложении - C (СИ)

Tags: c, массивы, строки, вывод

Есть текст, который содержится в массиве str. Каждое новое предложение нужно выводить с новой строки с отметкой о количестве символов в нём. Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать данный счётчик. Вывод предложения с новой строки уже реализован.
    -

```
for (int j = 0; str[j]; j++)
    {
        if(str[j] == '.')
        {
            printf(".\n");
            //где-то тут должен быть счётчик(amount)
            printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Amount of characters: %d\n", amount);
            printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            putchar(str[j]);
        }
        amount = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Перенесите на место комментария `amount = 0;` А в ветке else делайте ++amount. Тогда перед обнулением в amount будет количество символом. Правда со знаками препинания и пробелами. Если они должны исключаться - внесите это указание в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что количество символов надо выводить **до** предложения?
Тогда я бы поступил иначе, раз уж у вас точка - конец предложения, а конец предложения - точка :)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char str[] = "ghvsdavad sdghasdf. sahghbsd sdhbjhabsd. jghsdvjghvsdg hsdbjhbsd. jhjhs";
    for(char * s = str; *s; )
    {
        char * dot = strchr(s,'.');
        if (dot)
        {
            *dot = 0;
        }
        // Если нужно убрать пробелы вначале
        while(*s == ' ') ++s;

        printf("%2d  %s.\n",strlen(s),s);
        if (dot)
        {
            *dot = '.';
            s = dot+1;
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

Т.е. просто находим точку, обрезаем по ней строку, убираем, если нужно, ведущие пробелы и выводим получившуюся строку, предваряя ее длиной. Восстанавливаем точку и продолжаем со следующего за ней символа.